# Make all jQuery Accordion sections always close on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, accordion

I have download the [jQuery Accordion](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/) for my site.  I don't have any idea about jQuery. When the site opens all the sections of the accordion should close. I made some changes with these options...

```
-------------------------
//default
-------------------------
    jQuery().ready(function(){
        // simple accordion
        jQuery('#list1a').accordion();
        jQuery('#list1b').accordion({
            alwaysOpen: false,
            autoheight: true
        });
--------------------------
//Changed 
--------------------------
    jQuery().ready(function(){
        // simple accordion
        jQuery('#list1a').accordion();
        jQuery('#list1b').accordion({
            alwaysOpen: true,
            autoheight: false
        });

<--------------------------->
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
jQuery().ready(function(){
    // simple accordion
    jQuery('#list1a').accordion();
    jQuery('#list1b').accordion({
        alwaysOpen: false,
        active: false
    });
```

Comment: Ooh That's Great.that was a little thing i was wondering for.Thank You so much.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the jQuery UI Accordion:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

You can start it with just one line:

```
$(function(){ $('.accordion').accordion() });
```

You can select all elements to start closed with the active option set to false and collapsible set to true:

```
$(function(){ $('.accordion').accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false }) });
```

Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have  the `$(document).ready(function(){....});` in your script code? [More reading](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready)